# How can I get total pages from per page item count and total item count API response?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging-library

I'm fetching data froma remove endpoint. Data response only contains total item count but no total page. How can I calculate total pages given that I only have total item count and per page item count? I need this because I'm trying to setup paging library

for example:

```
perPage = 10
totalItemCount = 10
totalPages = 1
```

The idea is totalItemCount is greater than 10 + 1 but lower than or equal 20, totalPages would be 2; And totalItemCount > 10 + 10 + 1 but lower than or equal 30, totalPages = 3 and so on...

I couldn't make a good algo to calculate this using Kotlin

Comment: I think you want to use a combination of division and modulus: `totalPages = (totalItemCount / perPage) + (totalItemCount % perPage ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: this would handle the scenarios?

Comment: This would return 0 pages if `totalItemCount` is 0, 1 page if `totalItemCount` is 1-10, 2 pages if it is 11-20, and so on.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Testing

Comment: Check for syntax because I haven't written a single line of Kotlin in my life. And try to understand what division (`/`), modulus (`%`) and the ternary operator (`?`) do. You can write it in other ways, but try to get the idea behind that line.

Comment: Ah that's why I'm facing syntax error

Comment: What  I get is if (tottalItemCount divided by perPage) plus (totalCount modulus perPage) return 1 else return 0

Comment: You have to divide `totalItemCount` by `perPage`. And then, if the remainder of that division is not zero, you have to add 1. And you get the remainder using modulus.

Comment: Yeah sound simmple but I'm unable to translate into code. Do you write Java? If so you can make an aswer in Java then or C++ but without ternary please

Comment: Try this: `totalPages = totalItemCount / perPage`. Followed by `totalPages = if (totalItemCount % perPage == 0) totalPages else (totalPages + 1)`.

Comment: Did something similar. let me change few things

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working or my implemenation is wrong

Comment: Approaching from a different angle, which part of the Paging API is requiring you to compute the total number of pages?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work. I have tried it in https://pl.kotl.in/hUDoamkG3:

```
fun main()
{
    val listOfTotalItemCounts = listOf(0, 1, 9, 10, 15, 19, 20, 21, 124)
    val perPage = 10
    
    for (totalItemCount in listOfTotalItemCounts)
    {
        var result = (totalItemCount / perPage)
        result = if (totalItemCount % perPage == 0) result else (result + 1)
        
        print("When totalItemCount = ")
        print(totalItemCount)
        print(" ---> result = ")
        println(result)
    }
}
```

It yields the following output:

```
When totalItemCount = 0 ---> result = 0
When totalItemCount = 1 ---> result = 1
When totalItemCount = 9 ---> result = 1
When totalItemCount = 10 ---> result = 1
When totalItemCount = 15 ---> result = 2
When totalItemCount = 19 ---> result = 2
When totalItemCount = 20 ---> result = 2
When totalItemCount = 21 ---> result = 3
When totalItemCount = 124 ---> result = 13
```